# How to make a black and white two column alternating grid with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am mapping through an array and want the output to be the following:

```
Array.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).map((number, index) => console.log(index))

// 0-white 1-black 2-black 3-white 4-white 5-black 6-black 7-white 8-white 9-black
```

How can I do this using the index of `Array.map`?

For context, I am mapping through a list of items to display on a two column grid. I need to use JS, therefore the `index` needs to infer the correct color and can't use CSS in this scenario.

I can't for the life of me figure out the math logic to get the color correct.

Comment: `(index % 2) == 0 ? "white" : "black"`

Comment: @LeeTaylor, this is incorrect, this gives me "black, white, black, white, black, white". 
I need "white, black, black, white white, black, black". With your solution, In a two column grid, only one side is black and other side is white.

Comment: Why are you restricting yourself to using map here?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I am not, but my data is an array, and I need to loop through it

Comment: Your question implies that you want two results per row.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Just for you Lee I've put it on one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to XOR the lowest 2 bits of `index`, that will give you a pattern of `0,1,1,0` which can then be translated into `black` and `white`:

```js
result = Array.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
  .map((_, index) => (index & 1) ^ (index >> 1 & 1) ? 'black' : 'white')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like

```js
const pattern = ["white", "black", "black", "white"];
  
Array.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).map((_, i) => {
  console.log(i, pattern[i % pattern.length])
})
```

Comment: This works great too, I didn't think about using that pattern method. Will take note of that for the future